# Integrate JavaCC gradle plugin with Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, javacc

I have successfully set up a very basic cloud project in android studio following [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld). Further, I have added JavaCC support to the project using [this gradle plugin](https://github.com/johnmartel/javaccPlugin). I can now put my *.jj files in the javacc folder and have them compiled by using the compileJavacc task from within android studio. My `build.gradle` file now looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.14'
        classpath "ca.coglinc:javacc-gradle-plugin:2.0.4"
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin: "ca.coglinc.javacc"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```

Being a gradle and android studio beginner, I am not sure how to continue with the following:

1. Have the files generated by javaCC added to my build path
2. Having the JavaCC compile task run automatically when the *.jj files change.

How would I solve those two things in the most elegant way?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this specifically involve Android studio do you think?  If not, this question might garner more exposure if you simplify the title to something like 'Build compile dependency and buildpath using JavaCC plugin with my Gradle project'

Comment: Lennart, have you been able to solve #1? If so, then how?

Comment: Sorry to say, I gave up the project I was working on. Turned out there were other more sinister reasons why dynamically compiling and running java code from GAE was not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facing exactly the same problem and experimenting with different solutions, I've chosen the one shown below.

```
android {
    // ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'build/generated/javacc']
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.dependsOn.add(compileJavacc)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: txors alotzors. I will mark this as the right answer trusting you that it works since I no longer have any dev setup where JavaCC or Android Studio is a part.

Comment: Thanks Lennart.  This approach works for me.  May be there are better ways of doing this, but I'll stick with this for now.